# Change Front Page Word Press 4.1

Tags: frontpage

I simply want change which page is defined as the front page. It is currently my About Me page; I want it to be the page called Home. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Reading -> Front Page Displays. Set it to Static Page and choose your Home from the drop-down.